# three.js: My planes has a dark side to them

Tags: javascript, three.js

When I make a plane in three.js, like this:

```
plane = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 10, 10 ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xe0e0e0 } ) );
plane.position = somePoint;
plane.lookAt( someOtherPoint );
scene.add( plane );
```

the plane is only vissible from one side. The other side is invisible. I have tried changing the background color and the other side still doesn't show.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should talk to your planes; maybe get them some counseling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
plane.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
```

or alternatively,

```
THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xe0e0e0, side: THREE.DoubleSide } )
```

three.js r.51

I hope your planes feel better.